# Sql query works in MYSQL but not in SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a select query:

```
SELECT *, 
      COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM dbo.vKnjiga 
WHERE Datum = "2022-05-13" 
GROUP BY Naziv, Naslov, Koda_VP 
HAVING cnt >1;
```

It works in MySQL but when I put it into a SQL server it out puts:

> Invalid column name '2022-05-13'
> Invalid column name 'cnt'

Comment: *Does* your table have a column `2022-05-13` and `cnt`? Presumably, for the former, you should be using single quotes (`'`) for *literal strings*, not double quotes (`"`) for ANSI delimit identifying, and for the `HAVING`, you need to repeat the expression; you can't reference a column by its alias in the same scope anywhere other than the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: MySQL allows aliases in HAVING or WHERE, but SQL Server - does not. Correct your code to "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"

Comment: Don't just expect SQL in one dialect to run in another. MySQL and SQL Server's dialects are *very* different.

Comment: you also cannot have select * with a group by in sql server you can select only columns that are listed in the group by and results of aggregate functions (like count) so in your case `select Naziv, Naslov, Koda_VP, count(*) from..`

Comment: I suppose, technically, you *could* have `SELECT *` in SQL Server, but you would need to `GROUP BY` *every* column in the table; which makes the aggregation somewhat pointless as presumably the `COUNT` would then be `1` for *every* row (assuming they have a unique identifier).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least GROUP BY count(*).  Naziv, Naslov, Koda_VP soound like values, not column or aggregate names.